# Sticky Header Logo Hover

Tags: javascript, html, web

I found this website today http://www.mcdonalds.de/. Does anyone know how to make a sticky header like this? Only logo scroll down the navigation hide and  logo hover show the navigation. 
if any on can can help me out with coding or any resource that helps me to create the same. Your reply would be of great help to me.

Comment: You just give `position:fixed` to the header, put transition all xms linear or whatever, and use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) to detect for example 80px scroll and hide the header

Comment: Detect scrollTop, add `minimized` class to header when scroll, change display property of menus and width of the nav. For the animated effect, use the `transition` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a ridiculous implementation but I think you might get the idea.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var $container = $(".container");
  var container_offset = $container.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(container_offset);
  if(container_offset){
    $container.addClass('fixed');
  }else{
    $container.removeClass('fixed');
  }

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #3498db;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.container.fixed .header {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 900px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
.container.fixed .header ul {
  display: none;
}
.container.fixed .main {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  float: left;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  min-height: 1000px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
<header class="header">
  <h1>logo</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
  
<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique fugiat eveniet reprehenderit, nesciunt asperiores enim quaerat, totam laboriosam ratione sapiente corporis, ullam cum et vitae hic dolor in blanditiis quas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique fugiat eveniet reprehenderit, nesciunt asperiores enim quaerat, totam laboriosam ratione sapiente corporis, ullam cum et vitae hic dolor in blanditiis quas.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique fugiat eveniet reprehenderit, nesciunt asperiores enim quaerat, totam laboriosam ratione sapiente corporis, ullam cum et vitae hic dolor in blanditiis quas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique fugiat eveniet reprehenderit, nesciunt asperiores enim quaerat, totam laboriosam ratione sapiente corporis, ullam cum et vitae hic dolor in blanditiis quas.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique fugiat eveniet reprehenderit, nesciunt asperiores enim quaerat, totam laboriosam ratione sapiente corporis, ullam cum et vitae hic dolor in blanditiis quas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique fugiat eveniet reprehenderit, nesciunt asperiores enim quaerat, totam laboriosam ratione sapiente corporis, ullam cum et vitae hic dolor in blanditiis quas.</p>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Wowww perfekt only one think in fixed with mouse over effect and its super

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create it by yourself. But I think you want a quick and easy solution.

That's why I would recommend to use this: 
http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

If you want to create it by yourself I would recommend to use jQuery at least. Read about these topics:

- [CSS3 Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)
- [jQuery .animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [jQuery scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)
- [CSS Positioning (Section Fixed)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
- [jQuery toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [jQuery .offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

What you have to do is:
Create two classes
One of them looks like the "big bar" and one like the "small bar"
Triggering the scroll event executes the class change (toggle). You have to animate it via transition or jQuery .animate. You can get via the ".offset" method whether the element is at the top (offset = 0) or not.

I've created an example for you. You have to replace the button click event with a scroll event. You also have to check which value the offset has. If it's at the top use the class "big" otherwise "small".

You have to add a "position: fixed" to the CSS of the header (#header). The div is then "glued" to the top of the window. You'll achieve this effect where the rest of the content scroll behind the header bar.

```js
function scrollybolly(){
  
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  
  if(header.className == "big"){
    header.className = "small";
  }else{
    header.className = "big";
  }

}
```

```css
.big{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid black 1px;
 }

.small{
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }

#header{
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease;
-moz-transition: width 2s ease;
-ms-transition: width 2s ease;
-o-transition: width 2s ease;
transition: width 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="big"></div>
<Button onClick="scrollybolly()">Click here to simulate a scroll event</Button>
```

What I've used:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Even though you provide a lot of reading material, you don't *solve* a question. You only give some sources to look into. Therefore, it should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: We really can't write him this bunch of code (imho). I take stackoverflow as a learning platform and not as a "pls do my work" portal.

Comment: Correct. That's why I voted to close. Nevertheless, your post should've been no more than a comment. After your edit it is more or less fine.

Comment: @BramVanroy Yeah, you are right. I've added some code :) What are you saying? Ok this way?

Comment: Hallo Thx for the tips but is ther any Example i am not so good in jquery can some one post a example on http://jsfiddle.net thx i advance for help

Comment: @JohnKater I've added an example without jQuery. You just have to click on "Run code snippet". It's pretty much the same as jsfiddle.

Comment: @JohnKater Please feel free to mark my answer as correct :)